# Regex Pattern for name and contact

Tags: javascript, java, html, regex, string

How do I create a regex pattern which accepts this:

**For Name:**

1. first name = only accpets alphabet minimum of 4 and max of 10 but don't accept space at first and must have space after for the second name or middle initial
2. Second name = optional but only accpets alphabet minimum of 4 and max of 10 and must have space after for middle initial
3. Middle Initial = only one character which is an alphabet and followed by dot ( i.e "P." )
4. Last name = only accpets alphabet minimum of 4 and max of 10 but don't accept space after

**Examples:**

John Paul B. Seda 
John B. Seda

so far this is my pattern `^[\S\s]{3,21}[A-z0-9]+$` I can't figure out how can I do this.

**For Contacts:**

The pattern is like this: `(+63)9##-####-###`

1. Mandatory (+63)9##-
2. [0-9]- (characters should be only 4 followed by dash(-) )
3. [0-9] (characters should be only 3)

**Example:**

(+63)955-5555-555

Please help me. I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: what language is it for?

Comment: It is for the required of the html (pattern of html 5)

Comment: Names are not regular. People have strange names. Doing this will upset your users with strange names.

Comment: @Pescis what pattern do you suggest?

Comment: @CrayonViolent I also need it in java too.

Comment: I suggest just making a first, "middle" and last name field (3 separate fields). Allow for the "middle" field be an optional catchall for second name, middle name, etc..

Comment: I wouldn't ever perform regex validation on names. Names can be influenced by many cultural factors and limiting a person's options for name entry can be quite insulting to certain individuals, such as those with "bin" (Arabic for "son of") in their name or characters that are rare in latin-based languages, such as hypens, apostrophes and/or accents.

Comment: @Daemon I see. But the web app will only be use locally.

Comment: @newbie Is it impossible for one of your users to have migrated from another region to your location?

Comment: @Daemon Its not impossible but that would be a 1 in a million chance. I'm still thinking if I should only have a pattern for spaces.

Comment: @newbie I don't know about you, but even if my name is that one in a million, I would not appreciate being told that I cannot enter my name into this application because it is an "invalid" name.

Comment: @newbie you can have names such as Bill O'Reilly (which isn't that uncommon for someone from US and Europe) or a hyphenated last name (Katarina Johnson-Thompson - see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-barrelled_name)).  Even apostrophes in first names are seen on occasion - "D'Andre Payne" for example.

Comment: @newbie More importantly, you shouldn't restrict the user because the user (almost always) knows what they want better than the programmer does. Assuming that the program knows better is the #1 flaw in both Windows and Mac OSX, and is the reason most programmers prefer linux.

Comment: obLink: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name:

```
           ┌─ [ ] lowercase      { } 3 to 9 times  ─┐
           │                                        │
           │        ┌─ \x20 spacebar                │
         ┌─┴─┐     ┌┴─┐                           ┌─┴─┐
^(?:[A-Z][a-z]{3,9}\x20){1,2}[A-Z]\.\x20[A-Z][a-z]{3,9}$
│   └─┬─┘              │           │                   │
│     │                │           └─ \. period        │
│     │                │                               │
│     │                └─ (?: ) grouping               │
│     │                                                │
│     └─ [ ] uppercase letter        $ end of string ──┘
│
└─ ^ beginning of the string
```

Phone Number:

```
   ┌── \+ plus sign (needs to be escaped by \)
   │
   │           ┌── - minus sign (does not have to be escaped by \)
   │           │
^\(\+63\)9\d{2}-\d{4}-\d{3}$
 │     │        │
 │     │        └─ \d digit
 │     │
 │     └─ \) right parenthesis
 │         
 └─ \( left parenthesis
```

Comment: can you explain a bit the pattern so that in the future I can recreate it?

Comment: +1 Excellent explanation. Omega can you help me with just one last pattern? So I won't open a new question? I just want to make a pattern of this `Day, time` ( ie. Monday, 8:00a-5:00p ) either `a` or `p` in the time. I tried this `^(?:[A-Z][a-z]{9},)$` for the day but seems not working.

Comment: Use `^(?:Mon|Tues|Wednes|Thurs|Fri|Satur|Sun)day\x20` for day followed by spacebar...

Comment: `(?:(?:(?:8|9|10|11)(?=.{3}a)|(?:12|[1-4])(?=.{3}p)):[0-5]\d[ap]|5:00p)$` for time part

Comment: The pattern in your time what is the difference with one I made? `[1-9]:\d{2}(?:a|A|p|P)-[1-9]:\d{2}(?:a|A|p|P)`

Comment: @newbie - You cannot expect to learn regular expressions here. Your pattern is wrong. Sorry...

Comment: I thought so. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't ever validate names using regular expressions, as names are not regular. There is no single pattern that is universally adhered to when it comes to human names.

Phone numbers are much simpler, they are required to adhere to a single pattern and it is possible for phone numbers to be invalid.

A simple regex to match your needs would likely be thus: `^\(\+63\)9\d{2}-\d{4}-\d{3}$`.\

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Pattern simply matches `(+63)9` + `2 digits [0-9]` + `-` + `4 digits [0-9]` + `-` + `3 digits [0-9]`.

Comment: can you explain a bit the pattern so that in the future I can recreate it?

Comment: so the `\\(\\` you used string escape character?